# ArcPy Report syntax error

Tags: arcpy, runtimeerror, valueerror, assertionerror

I'm working on trying to use arcpy to automate the creation of a report, but I'm running into a problem.

```
>>> arcpy.mapping.ExportReport('2013pp',"C:\reports\2013_Graffiti.rlf","C:\reports\2013_Graffiti_report.pdf")

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 506, in ExportReport
    assert isinstance(report_source, (MapDocument, TableView, Layer)), str(type(report_source))
AssertionError: <type 'str'>
```

I'm having trouble deciphering the traceback as it seems to reference a variety of internal python files. In trouble shooting so far, I thought the problem might be that the report_source needs to be a layer file and I was using a .shp so I converted to a .lyr but then I get the error:

```
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)
```

In response to the suggestions below, I've tried the following with full paths, but am receiving the same error.

```
>>> arcpy.mapping.ExportReport('2013pp',r"C:\reports\Graffiti.rlf", r"C:\reports\2013_Graffiti_report.pdf")
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 506, in ExportReport
    assert isinstance(report_source, (MapDocument, TableView, Layer)), str(type(report_source))
AssertionError: <type 'str'>
```

When I try Blord's suggestion I get the following:

```
>>> arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(arcpy.mapping.Layer('2013pp.lyr'),"C:\reports\2013_Graffiti.rlf","C:\reports\2013_Graffiti_report.pdf")
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 389, in __init__
    super(LayerMixin, self).__init__(lyrfile)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 47, in __init__
    for arg in args))
ValueError: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source
>>>
```

The last part about the invalid data source makes me wonder about whether the shape file is acceptable...it should be given that I am able to manually create a report with it.

As an aside, is this only an arcpy mapping tool, i.e. I can't find it in ModelBuilder or in a toolbox?

I was hoping to try to trouble shoot by creating the tool in ModelBuilder, exporting it and examining the script.

Comment: Yers, a shapefile will not work. A shapefile does not have the symbology information that a layer file does. I think that you can only do this tool with arcpy.mapping or the Report tools in the UI (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004v00000002000000)

Answer (score 5):

`mapping.py` is running an assertion test to make sure that your report source is a MapDocument, TableView, or Layer. This is the first argument you provided.

And it is not a MapDocument, TableView, or Layer, it is a string. That is what `AssertionError: <type 'str'>` means.

Instead of giving the string `'2013pp'` you need a reference directly to 2013pp as a Layer object. Try:

`arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(arcpy.mapping.Layer(u'C:\\project\\2013pp.lyr'),u'C:\\Py‌​thon\\reports\\2013_Graff‌​iti.rlf', u'C:\\report.pdf')`

What I have done here is turn the string into a Layer object in the middle of the function arguments. Edit: Modified based on full path to .lyr file. Also converted all strings to unicode

Comment: I've edited the original post to indicate the results when I tried this, unfortunately: unsuccessful.

Comment: Try the full path to the .lyr file.

Comment: still doesn't work with the full path to the layer file, gives same error as before    arcpy.mapping.ExportReport("C:\project\2013pp.lyr","C:\\Python\reports\2013_Graffiti.rlf", "C:\report.pdf")

Comment: You left out the class creation with arcpy.mapping.Layer. Just to make sure it is not a raw versus unicode string problem too, try `arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(arcpy.mapping.Layer(u'C:\\project\\2013pp.lyr'),u'C:\\Python\\reports\\2013_Graff‌​iti.rlf', u'C:\\report.pdf')` I modified the answer above to reflect this version.

Comment: I don't think so, as I got this error with that: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Comment: What is the exact line you used? That indicates that four arguments went into arcpy.mapping.Layer() instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a path issue, try example below.

e.g.

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportReport('2013pp',r"C:\reports\2013_Graffiti.rlf",r"C:\reports\2013_Graffiti_report.pdf")
```

Comment: I've edited the original post to indicate the results when I tried this, unfortunately: unsuccessful.